Exercise 2.8 from Billingsley
In Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures, Exercise 2.8 asks:
Suppose $\delta_{x_n}\Rightarrow P$. Then $P=\delta_x$ for some $x$.
Here, $\delta_{x}(A)=\textbf{1}_A(x)$ is the unit mass. Without any additional hypotheses provided, I assume he wants us to work on a general metric space $S$, but that seems to cause some problems. Below are my attempts. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
It suffices to show that $x_n\to x$ for some $x\in S$, as then, if $f$ is bounded and continuous,
\begin{align*}
    |Pf-\delta_xf|&\leq|Pf-\delta_{x_n}f|+|\delta_{x_n}f-\delta_xf|\\
    &=|Pf-\delta_{x_n}f|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|
\end{align*}
which goes to zero as $n\to\infty$.
If we assume $x_n$ has a limit point, the proof is nice and quick. To see this limit point must be unique, let $x_1\neq x_2$ be two limit points of $x_n$. Take $\varepsilon$ small enough so that $\overline{B(x_1,\varepsilon)}\cap\overline{B(x_2,\varepsilon)}=\varnothing$. Now $x_n\in \overline{B(x_1,\varepsilon)}$ and $x_n\in \overline{B(x_1,\varepsilon)}$ infinitely often, so $1=\limsup \delta_{x_n}\overline{B(x_1,\varepsilon})\leq P(\overline{B(x_1,\varepsilon)})$ and likewise for $x_2$, and thus
\begin{align*}
    P(S)&\geq P(\overline{B(x_1,\varepsilon)}\cup\overline{B(x_2,\varepsilon)})\\
    &=P(\overline{B(x_1,\varepsilon)})+P(\overline{B(x_2,\varepsilon)})\\
    &=2
\end{align*}
a contradiction. Now without this assumption, let's see what problems may arise. It would be great to show that $x_n$ eventually lives on a compact set $K$, as every sequence on a compact metric space has a convergent subsequence. To this end, assume that $S$ is separable and complete. Then by tightness, we may choose a compact set $K$ such that $PK>3/4$. $K$ is bounded, so take any bounded open set $G\supset K$. Now
\begin{align*}
\liminf \delta_{x_n}\overline{G}\geq\liminf \delta_{x_n}G\geq PG\geq PK>3/4
\end{align*}
by Portmanteau. But $\liminf \delta_{x_n}\overline{G}\in\{0,1\}$, and so $x_n\in \overline{G}$ eventually. Now, if $\overline{G}$ were compact we would be done. However, from my understanding, closed and bounded does not imply compact in general. We would need to take $S$ to be totally bounded for that to occur, but this excludes the possibility of $S$ even being $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. (If we did that, existence of a convergent subsequence would follow directly without $\delta_{x_n}\Rightarrow P$.) If we didn't want to assume total boundedness, we could also consider trying to insert $G\text{ open }\subset K$. If we knew of the existence of such a set with $P(K-G)<1/4$, for example, then
\begin{align*}
\liminf \delta_{x_n}K\geq\liminf \delta_{x_n}G\geq PG= PK-P(K-G)>1/2
\end{align*}
and so $x_n\in K$ eventually. This seems promising, but we cannot guarantee the existence of such a $G$ for arbitrary measures $P$ and closed sets $K$. Regularity applies to $F\text{ closed }\subset K$.

Edit: A solution --
Suppose $\delta_{x_n}\Rightarrow P$. Then $P=\delta_x$ for some $x$.
We use the following equivalences from Portmanteau's Theorem:
$P_n\Rightarrow P\iff\limsup P_nF\leq PF$ for all closed $F\iff\liminf P_nG\geq PG$ for all open $G$
It suffices to show that $x_n\to x$ for some $x\in S$, as then, if $f$ is bounded and continuous,
\begin{align*}
    |Pf-\delta_xf|&\leq|Pf-\delta_{x_n}f|+|\delta_{x_n}f-\delta_xf|\\
    &=|Pf-\delta_{x_n}f|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|
\end{align*}
which goes to zero as $n$ approaches infinity.
Assume $\{x_n\}$ has a limit point. To see it must be unique, let $x_1\neq x_2$ be two limit points of $\{x_n\}$. Take $\delta$ small enough so that $\overline{B(x_1,\delta)}\cap\overline{B(x_2,\delta)}=\varnothing$. Now $x_n\in \overline{B(x_1,\delta)}$ and $x_n\in \overline{B(x_1,\delta)}$ infinitely often, so $1=\limsup \delta_{x_n}\overline{B(x_1,\delta})\leq P(\overline{B(x_1,\delta)})$ and likewise for $x_2$, and thus
\begin{align*}
    P(S)&\geq P(\overline{B(x_1,\delta)}\cup\overline{B(x_2,\delta)})\\
    &=P(\overline{B(x_1,\delta)})+P(\overline{B(x_2,\delta)})\\
    &=2
\end{align*}
a contradiction.
Now we establish the existence of a limit point. Assume instead nonexistence. Then, in particular, $\{x_n\}$ has no limit points in $S-\{x_n\}$, and so for all $y\in S-\{x_n\}$, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(y,\varepsilon)\cap \{x_n\}=\varnothing$. If $\rho(y',y)<\varepsilon/2$, then $B(y',\varepsilon/2)\subset B(y,\varepsilon)$, and so $B(y',\varepsilon)\cap \{x_n\}=\varnothing$, which shows $S-\{x_n\}$ is open and $\{x_n\}$ is closed. Write $A=\{x_n\}=\cup_{i=1}^\infty \{x_i\}$. Now, by Portmanteau,
\begin{align*}
    1=\limsup(\delta_{x_n}A)\leq P(A)\leq\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(\{x_i\})\
\end{align*}
And so there exists $x\in \{x_n\}$ with $P(\{x\})>0$. Let $\delta>0$. Then, again by Portmanteau,
\begin{align*}
    \liminf\delta_{x_n}(B(x,\delta))\geq P(B(x,\delta))\geq P(\{x\})>0
\end{align*}
But $\liminf\delta_{x_n}(B(x,\delta))\in\{0,1\}$, so $\liminf\delta_{x_n}(B(x,\delta))=1$. Given $\delta$ is arbitrary, $x$ is not only a limit point of $\{x_n\}$, but the sole limit. But this is a contradiction, and so $\{x_n\}$ must have a limit point. By our previous computation, it is unique.

Edit: An shorter proof -- assuming $S$ is separable and complete
As above, it suffices to show $x_n\to x$ for some $x\in S$. Supposing one exists, the uniqueness of a limit point of $\{x_n\}$ is shown in the above proof. Here we show existence.
Assuming $S$ is separable and complete, then $P$ is tight, so take $K$ to be a compact set in $S$ such that $PK>1/2$. Assume $\{x_n\}$ has no limit points in $S$. Then for each $x\in S$, there exists $\varepsilon_x>0$ such that $\{x_n\}\in B(x,\varepsilon_x)$ finitely often. Now $U=\cup_{x\in S}B(x,\varepsilon_x)$ is an open cover of $K$, so we get a finite subcover $\cup_{i=1}^mB(x_i,\varepsilon_{x_i})$. We have
\begin{align*}
    \liminf \delta_{x_n}\cup_{i=1}^mB(x_i,\varepsilon_{x_i})&\geq P\cup_{i=1}^mB(x_i,\varepsilon_{x_i})\\
    &\geq PK\\
    &>1/2
\end{align*}
So $\{x_n\}\in \cup_{i=1}^mB(x_i,\varepsilon_{x_i})$ eventually, and thus there exists a $B(x,\varepsilon_x)\subset S$ such that $\{x_n\}\in B(x,\varepsilon_x)$ infinitely often, contradicting our assumption on $S$.

Here the same question and another answer.

@Snoop: In the link you gave $S=\mathbb{R}$. In the OP's case, he is interested in the case where $S$ is a general metric space where Fourier transform may not be defined and where $S$ may fail to be separable as $\mathbb{R}$ is. Granted, the problem in Bogachev's says even more: the statement is valid not only for metric spaces but for completely regular spaces.

@Mittens indeed I should have mentioned that the point of my comment was highlighting Bogachev's exercise: for reference here it's 8.10.67 in Vol .II

@Patrick: I think that from this exercise you can also derive the following result: a set $K\subset S$ has compact closure iff $\mathcal{K}={\delta_x:x\in K}$ is compact in $\mathcal{P}(S)$ under the weak topology. In one direction is easy: the map $x\mapsto \delta_x$ is continuous. In the other direction if $\mathcal{K}$ weakly compact, then it is also close ($C_b(S)$ separate points and this the weak topology is locally convex and Hausdorfff) If $(\delta_{x_n}) $ is a convergent sequence, then the exercise implies that $x_n$ converges.

@Mittens I'm not familiar with all those concepts, so that'll be an exercise for another time for me. Also, as a follow-up, my counterexample to every probability measure on a metric space having non-empty support does fail. My purported measure P has only finite additivity, but not countable additivity.

When $S$ is separable,  perhaps more direct proof can be given as follows.
Fix $x\in\operatorname{supp}(P)$. For any open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ let $f\in C_b(S)$ such that $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f(x)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in S\setminus V$. Then $\delta_{x_n}f=f(x_n)=\int_Sf\,d\mu>0$. This means that there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N$, then $f(x_n)>0$ and so $x_n\in V$. This implies that $x_n\rightarrow x$. The conclusion then follows immediately: if $g\in C_b(S)$,
$$\delta_{x_n}g=g(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=\delta_xg$$
That is $\delta_{x_n}\Longrightarrow \delta_x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Uniqueness follows from the fact that $C_b(S)$ is a separating family for the space of probability (Borel) measures in $S$.
Remark: Here we use the fact that if $S$ is separable  and $\mu$ is a non-zero measure on the Borel sets of $S$, then $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)\neq\emptyset$.

For a general metric space, Paresseux Nguyen presented a sketch of a solution here.  It goes like this:

If $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)\neq\emptyset$, the conclusion follows as in the case where $S$ is separable.

If $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence and say $x_{n_k}\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}x$ in $S$, then
it is easy to check that $\delta_{x_{n_k}}\stackrel{k\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow}\delta_x$; thus,  (i) $P=\delta_x$ and (ii) the original sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$.

Suppose the sequence $(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ does not have a convergent subsequence in $S$. Then, no element of the sequence appears infinitely often for otherwise one can subtract a constant subsequence and thus a convergent subsequence. It follows that   $A=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$  is infinite and has no limit point (here we say that $y$ is limit point of a set $C$ if for any $\varepsilon>0$, $C\cap(B(y;\varepsilon)\setminus\{y\})\neq\emptyset$). It follows that $A=\overline{A}$ and that each element of the sequence is an isolated point of $A$. Furthermore, every point $x\in S\setminus A$ admits an open neighborhood which contains no point in $A$.
Now, consider the map $g(y)=1\wedge d(y,\overline{A})$. Observe that  $g\in C^+_b(S)$, and that $g(y)=0$ iff $y\in A$. By hypothesis,
$$0=\delta_{x_n}g\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}P g$$
Hence $g=0$ $P$-a.s. Thus $P(A)=1$ and so,
$$P=\sum_na_n\delta_{x_n}$$
where $\sum_na_n=1$ and $a_n\geq0$. This implies that $\operatorname{supp}(P)\neq\emptyset$ and, as in the case of $S$ separable, we would have that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges. This however contradicts the assumption we made that $(x_n)$ has no convergent subsequence. Consequently, $(x_n)$ admits a convergent subsequence and in fact the whole sequence converges.



This was essentially what I first tried. The problem is there exist probability measures with empty "support," no matter how generous one is with that definition. What you assumed here is the existence of an open neighborhood with nonzero probability. Consider the space of integers Z with the usual metric. Define a probability measure P that assigns 0 to subsets of Z that are bounded and 1 to subsets that are unbounded. Fix x in Z. Then every open neighborhood of x has probability 0.

My S=Z above is separable, is it not? We can take the countable dense subset to be Z. Since each singleton is open, each subset is open. My measure u=P is regular. Am I misunderstanding something?

@Patrick: I made an edit addressing a general metric space. The idea is to show that the limit measure $P$ has nonempty support. This is shown by showing that $(x_n)$ must have a convergent subsequence. This is turn will imply that in fact that the sequence $x_n$ converges.

This proof in the general case was really helpful, for some reason I didn't think to show the set A = {x_n} becomes closed under the assumption {x_n} doesn't have a convergent subsequence. I think I've found a way to greatly simplify the argument using Portmanteau's theorem rather than the usual definition for weak convergence. I'll update my post in a bit. Thanks again!

Let $d$ denote the metric on $S$. Also, let $K = \overline{\{ x_n : x \in \mathbb{N} \}}$ denote the closure of the image of $(x_n)$. Then the lemma below will ensure that the sequence satisfying the condition will have a limit point:

Lemma. Under the assumption of the problem, $K$ is compact.

Proof of Lemma. Assume otherwise. Being an induced metric space, $K$ is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. Hence, $K$ is not compact if at least one of these two properties is violated.
In each of the cases, we will show that we can find a continuous, bounded function $f$ on $S$ such that $f(S) \subseteq [0, 1)$ and $\delta_{x_n} f \to 1$ (at least along a subsequence), thereby violating $Pf = \lim_{n\to \infty} \delta_{x_n}f$.

Case 1. If $K$ is not complete, then we can find a subsequence $(x_n)_{n\in J}$  which is Cauchy but does not converge in $K$. Since $K$ is closed in $S$, this means that $(x_n)_{n\in J}$ does not converge also in $S$. Now, define the two functions $\rho$ and $f$ on $S$ by
$$ \rho(x) = \lim_{J \ni n \to \infty} d(x, x_n), \qquad f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + \rho(x)}. $$
It is easy to check that the limit defining $\rho$ converges uniformly on $S$. Also, $\rho$ never vanishes on $S$. Hence, $f$ is continuous with the image satisfying $f(S) \subseteq [0, 1)$. So, if $\delta_{x_n} \Rightarrow P$ for some probability measure $P$ on $S$, then we must also have $P f < 1$. However, it is easy to check that
$$ \lim_{J \ni n \to \infty} \delta_{x_n} f = \lim_{J \ni n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 1. $$

Case 2. If $K$ is not totally bounded, we can find $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(x_n)_{n\in J}$ such that $\{ B(x_n, \varepsilon) \}_{n \in J}$ is a family of disjoint $\varepsilon$-balls. Then we enumerate $J = \{n_1, n_2, \ldots\}$ and define the function $f$ on $S$ by
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k+1} \max\biggl\{1 - \frac{2}{\varepsilon}d(x, x_{n_k}), 0 \biggr\}. $$
By the disjointness of the $\varepsilon$-balls, the above sum converges uniformly on $S$ and hence defines a continuous function. Moreover, each time only at most one term is non-zero, hence $f(x) < 1$ for all $x \in S$. Finally, it is clear that
$$ \delta_{x_{n_k}}f = \frac{k}{k+1} \to 1 $$


This completes the proof of the lemma. $\square$

This is a brilliant proof! I chose to proceed a little differently (and hopefully without error) in my solution, but used the same key idea of actually working with the set {x_n} rather than trying to find some other compact set in my metric space that contained it, as I had in my first attempt. Thanks again!
